# Recursively remove field(s) from object without mutating original object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, lodash

I am trying to remove fields(s) recursively from an object without mutating it.

Here is a sample object that I am working with. I am using lodash and removing the 'Authorization' field from the object. Note! Authorization appears twice so, both are removed.

```
const _ = require("lodash");

const error = {
  name: "name",
  errorType: "errorType",
  error: {
    name: "name",
    statusCode: 400,
    options: {
      uri: "example.com",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer 123456789012345678901234567890"
      },
      json: true,
      method: "POST",
      body: {
        a: 1
      },
      timeout: 2000,
      error: {
        key: "value"
      }
    },
    response: {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: {
        error_code: "errorCode"
      },
      headers: {
        date: "2020-01-01 10:20:30",
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      request: {
        uri: "example.com",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer 123456789012345678901234567890",
          accept: "application/json",
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "content-length": 123
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const omitKeys = (collection, keys) => {
  return _.cloneDeepWith(_.cloneDeep(collection), value => {
    if (_.isObject(value)) {
      _.forEach(keys, key => delete value[key]);
    }
  });
}

const result = omitKeys(error, ["Authorization"]);
```

RESULT:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "errorType": "errorType",
  "error": {
    "name": "name",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "options": {
      "uri": "example.com",
      "headers": {},
      "json": true,
      "method": "POST",
      "body": {
        "a": 1
      },
      "timeout": 2000,
      "error": {
        "key": "value"
      }
    },
    "response": {
      "statusCode": 400,
      "body": {
        "error_code": "errorCode"
      },
      "headers": {
        "date": "2020-01-01 10:20:30",
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      "request": {
        "uri": "example.com",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "accept": "application/json",
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "content-length": 123
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above logic works but the challenge is to achieve the same result without using the `delete` operator.

How to achieve the result without using the `delete` operator and without mutating the original object?

Comment: Since you cloned the object, you're not modifying the original.

Comment: The function is called "recursiveOmit`, but it's not recursive.